# Prevent user from printing/saving PDF file in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, data-protection, axacropdf

I am writing an application that views PDF files, this application uses **AxAcroPDFLib AxAcroPDF**

My problem here is that I want to prevent user from saving and/or printing PDF files that are being viewed in my application

Or in other words *I want to hide toolbar of the PDF viewer*

any ideas ?!

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using another plugin to view PDF files [PDF Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe)

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem now. How did you convert this to C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to hide the toolbar by

```
axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
```