# how to hide print button when pdf is opened in browser using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

```
protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbkFile = (LinkButton)sender;
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Improvementdata/" + lbkFile.CommandArgument);
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        string extn = Path.GetExtension(lbkFile.CommandArgument);
        if (extn == ".jpg" || extn == ".png" || extn == ".JPG" || extn == ".jpg")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: You don't want user to be able to print the pdf files?

Comment: i want disble user to save or print pdf file. user can only view the pdf file that's it. thanks

Comment: Once the file is opened in user's browser it is almost impossible to control what user can do with it. User can download the file and print it.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/8870518/8843433 hope this will help